# Unable to locate any server in SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008

I am a newbie.

I recently installed SQL Server 2008 on my server.

When I try to login, it does not show me any server when in Browse (see below)
[image]

What could be wrong?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the SQL Server Browser service is running on the server, and that your instances are also running.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Restart your server and make sure that your sql server services are running, also your instance services are running.

You can check that in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: Hi, I restarted the server and I still do not see anything in SQL Server Configuration Manager. What could be wrong?

Comment: you must have stopped services in you SQL Server Configuration Manager other wise you have not installed SQL server on your server.

Comment: Just to let you know that when I click SQL Server Services in SQL Configuration Manager, I do not see anything there. What could be the issue?

Comment: Which version of SQL server you have installed?

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Comment: It is not installed on your server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11980/discussion-between-meetpd-and-shaikh-farooque)

Answer (score 0):

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Mangement Studio with Management Tools and that solved my problem.

(en_sql_server_2008_r2_express_with_management_tools_x86.iso)

Comment: Probably that solved it because it will (if properly checked in setup) start your SQL Server Browser service, like CodeByMoonlight suggests. This is something to watch if installing/uninstalling instances of MSSQL, setup may turn on/off the Server Browser.